# Registering policy ID programatically (pool.pm)

Tags: nft, policy

I'm seeing many NFT minting policies registered on pool.pm, and I noticed they can be registered manually there as well.

Is there a way to do this programmatically? And is this a pool.pm-specific thing, or is there some kind of central registry?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Just open your network tools on yojr favorite browser and inspect the request which is made when submitting a script. Should be easy.

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of my last resort. I was just wondering if there was a more "official" way to do it, rather than hacking around it and risking things to be broken if Smaug decides to change their internal API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to currently do this programmatically, and yes - this feature is specific to pool.pm.